# How to generate random cloud-type shape in Python

Tags: python, random, shapes

Looking to generate an image file with a cloud-type shape with a known area in Python. Basically a random shape generator where I can set the area of the shape before it generates it. Generating multiple shapes would also be useful.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

By cloud I mean an image file that resembles randomly overlapping circles. I just need a shape that has relatively round edges. Im using it to test the accuracy of an image analysis protocol.

This turned out to be the best option: http://www.101computing.net/random-cloud-generator-using-python/

Played around with Processing and managed to get what I needed. Thanks for responses

Comment: Could you be more specific what you mean by "cloud shape"? Do you mean a fractal of some kind?

Comment: By Cloud I mean a shape that resembles randomly overlapping circles. I just need a shape that has relatively round edges. Im using it to test the accuracy of an image analysis protocol.

Comment: What do you mean with "shape"? On screen? In an image file? As an abstract set of data, such as coordinates and vectors?

Comment: An image file like this: http://www.101computing.net/random-cloud-generator-using-python/

Comment: ... So how exactly does that code in your link *not* do what you are asking?

Comment: I would like to be able to define the total area of the shape before it generates.

Answer (score 1):

Look into this.This might be what you are looking for or at least it will point you in the right direction.

http://www.101computing.net/random-cloud-generator-using-python/

You can use turtle.

```
import turtle

myTurtle = turtle.Turtle()
myTurtle.circle(50)
turtle.getscreen()._root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I saw this, but I would like to define the total area before it generates.

Comment: Im pretty new to Python. Would you be able to tell me how I go about generating a single circle? Are there other tools apart from Processing?